# Saving a CSV in Excel in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, encoding

I make a `.csv` file in Notepad++ with one character:

> á

I clicked "Encode in UTF-8" and saved the file as `test.csv`. Then I opened up the file in Excel and saw the output:

> Ã¡

The UTF-8 code points of `á` is `C3 A1`. Excel opens up CSV files in ANSI automatically, and these two bytes correspond to the characters shown in Excel 2013.

I then save this file in Excel, but while doing so go to Tools --> Web Options --> Encoding --> Save This Document as (Unicode - UTF-8) and as `test.csv` again.

If I were to then open this in Notepad++, encoded as UTF-8, I would then expect to see `Ã¡` as Excel just saved the file with those contents encoded as UTF-8. Instead I still see `á` as originally was the case. Is Excel ignoring my encoding option and still saving in ANSI?

Comment: It probably just changes the display to UTF-8 instead of ANSI the actual byte order would be the same. They're just interpreted differently. Using the Import Option for external data should give you the option to specify UTF-8.